# Changes to a stylesheet in one folder below the root do not take immediate effect with Brackets and XAMPP

Tags: bootstrap-4, xampp, adobe-brackets

I am using a CSS stylesheet along with Bootstrap, Adobe Brackets and XAMPP, running locally on my PC.  If I make a change to the css stylesheet, the change does not take immediate effect upon saving the stylesheet.  The system seems to remember the previous code in the stylesheet.  The changes eventually manifest themselves, but I can't find a rhyme or reason for this.  In other words, I make a change to the stylesheet but the change does not show up when I open the webpage in Bracket's Live Preview.

This problem does not happen if I place the css stylesheet in the root directory.  I cannot see what, if anything, I'm doing wrong. Here is my code showing the path to the stylesheet.  Given:  the folder css is only level beneath the root folder.

Here is my link to the CSS stylesheet.  What could be wrong?

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--  NR Systems -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/NatResConStyles.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question.

If a change to the CSS stylesheet is not immediately applied, or if a change to an image is not immediately applied, then you must use Google Chrome to "Clear Browsing Data/Cached Images and Files." Then refresh the web page. You should see that your changes have been applied.

This is in the development environment running Adobe Brackets, using the Live Preview feature, which uses Google Chrome.